# Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::with() when retrieving orders with providers and services

Tags: eloquent, laravel-8, laravel-query-builder

I am trying to retrieve orders with their service names and provider names all which are in a many to many relationship.
Additionally, I want to use joins to get the client, name.
I have thus used the code bellow

```
      $orders = DB::table('orders')
                ->join('users', 'orders.user', 'users.id')
                ->select('users.name As client', 'orders.id', 'orders.amount As amount','orders.description As description', 'orders.status As status')
                ->with('providers')
                ->with('services')
                ->where(['orders.status'=>1])
                ->get();
```

In the Order model class, I have implemented the relationships as follows

```
       public function providers() 
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(ServiceProvider::class)
    ->as('provider');
}
public function services() 
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Service::class)
    ->as('service');
}
```

With this I am expecting to retrieve each order with all the services and providers related to it and since I have a foreign key user linking orders to users table, I have used joins to get the name of the user who placed the order as client. Now my problem is that this is not working and is giving the error above. Does this mean that the with() method does not exist in database query builder? if so what method can I use with database query builder to achieve this? Incase there is none, how can I use eloquent ORM to achieve the same purpose?

Comment: "_Does this mean that the with() method does not exist in eloquent query builder?_" You're not using [Eloquent](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent), you're using the [Database: Query Builder](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries)

Comment: `DB::table('orders')` does not use your `Order.php` Model. You need to start your query with `Order:: ...`, so `Order::join(...)->select(...)->with(...)->where(...)->get()`

Comment: @brombeer updated the question. That was a typo

Comment: @TimLewis, add that as an answer so that I can accept it to help another person with the same issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use the `DB::table()` method, you are not using your Models, so the `->with()` method, which is used to include Relationships is not available. To handle this, please use your Models:

```php
$orders = Order::join('users', 'orders.user', 'users.id')
->select('users.name As client', 'orders.id', 'orders.amount As amount','orders.description As description', 'orders.status As status')
->with(['providers', 'services'])
->where('orders.status', 1)
->get();
```

Additional fixes:

The `->with()` method can accept an Array of relationships to include:

> `->with('providers')->with('services')` can be written as `->with(['providers', 'services'])`

The `where()` method can accept an array for multiple where clauses, but is unnecessary for a single where clause:

> `->where(['orders.status'=>1])` is the same as `->where('orders.status', 1)`